# How to extract oscdimg.exe from ADK CAB-file?

Tags: powershell, gzipstream, cab, adk

I have a project where I need to download the oscdimg.exe tool from the Windows 11 ASK. For this I have written this small PS-code which is doing the job, but it still uses the filesystem to store the interim CAB-file. Is there any way to do the extraction directly on the byte-array of the CAB-file in memory (e.g. via [System.IO.Compression])?

```
# download oscdimg-tool from Windows 11 ADK:

$tmp  = $env:temp
$cab  = '5d984200acbde182fd99cbfbe9bad133.cab'
$fil  = 'fil720cc132fbb53f3bed2e525eb77bdbc1'
$exe  = 'oscdimg.exe'
$adk  = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/f/d/1fd2291e-c0e9-4ae0-beae-fbbe0fe41a5a/adk/Installers/$cab"

if (!(Test-Path -Path "$tmp\$exe" -PathType Leaf)) {
    $null= Invoke-WebRequest $adk -OutFile "$tmp\$cab"
    $app = new-object -com shell.application
    $in  = $app.NameSpace("$tmp\$cab")
    $out = $app.NameSpace($tmp)
    $itm = $in.Items() | where {$_.Name -eq $fil}
    $out.CopyHere($itm, 16)
    Rename-Item "$tmp\$fil" "$exe" -ea 0
    Remove-Item "$tmp\$cab"
}
```

Comment: GZIP is compression, not ZIP/UNZIP.  The file is in the body of the HTTP Response.  You can extract the body into a Memory Stream.   Than UNZIP the memory stream  This question has be asked many times in c# postings.  The c# code can be converted to PS.

Comment: any link how to unzip a CAB-file (not a ZIP-file) would be welcome.

Comment: A Cab file is a ZIP file with a different extension.  So most ZIP utilities will allow you to remove files.  See : https://www.winzip.com/en/learn/file-formats/cab/?force_isolation=true

Comment: I made a lot of unzip-scripts in the past like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031711/how-to-download-only-a-single-file-from-an-online-zip-archive-via-powershell but the same logic does not work for MS-CAB files.

Comment: if I open the CAB-file in HEX-editor I can see that it has no PK-header and that the file-directory is at the beginning and not at the end as in a default ZIP-format.

Comment: this ref looks promising to make a custom parser around it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//bb267310(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#detailed-structure-specification

Comment: The ZIP specification has lots of options.  PK initial create ZIP, but then it became an industry standard.  So It may not be PK format, but still matches the specification.  Microsoft likes to change things even when they do not need to be changed.  Blame Microsoft if the file-directory is not at the beginning.  It is probably easier to add the directory at the end with cab file after all the files are inserted.

Comment: Why does Microsoft have its own compression format from 1997 according to your link?  At work somebody used the Microsoft format and thought it was unique.  I renamed the extension to zip and then opened it with PKZIP.

Comment: As this is a forum for coders can you please provide the code snippet you used to extract the CAB file?

Comment: Use same as ZIP.  You can search for "msdn c# class zip"

Comment: I tried that with the above CAB-file. Not working.