# Iterating over huge S3 zip file's entries without download- and as fast as possible

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to find a fast and efficient solution to iterate over a zip's entries, while it is located in S3. The zip file is huge (60-100GB+), and downloading is not a viable solution since we are limited in storage.

The iteration is for calculating the offset of each entry.

One way to do that is by creating an S3 stream, and using SharpZipLib to iterate over the entries. The problem is that this method simply "downloads" the entries one by one everytime, which is pretty slow.

I know that for calculating the entrie's offsets, I don't really need to download all the bytes everytime, but rather fetch specific bytes. This can be done in python, but can this also be done in C#? From the libraries which I tried (Ionic, sharpziplib), I couldn't find a way to a way to minimize the byte fetching as much as possible.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Even though I need the solution in C#, I tried to fetch the last 22 bytes of a simple zip in python, but I get an "ValueError: negative seek value -55"

```
import io
import zipfile

zip_file = "path/to/zip"
with open(zip_file, 'rb') as file:

    file.seek(-22, io.SEEK_END)
    cd_bytes = file.read()

cd_stream = io.BytesIO(cd_bytes)
cd_stream.seek(0)

zipfile_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(cd_stream, mode='r', allowZip64=True)

for filename in zipfile_obj.namelist():
    print(filename)
```

Comment: Zips have a duplicate directory at the end of the file. You could read backwards from the end of the file until you find the start of that, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593904/how-to-find-the-position-of-central-directory-in-a-zip-file although you might end up writing code to parse this yourself.

Comment: Ok sounds interesting. So If I start from the end, I have two questions:
1) How do I know which bytes are the EOCD / CD?
2)Can I load only the CD bytes into a ZipArchive objectin C#?
Because I will need to know the size of each file to skip and fetch the header bytes

EDIT: Ok. I see that I can iterate over enSize-22 until it works. But how do I know that I got the CD bytes?

Comment: What python library are you using?  Did you try with your S3 to see if it is working?  You can only open a remote S# file is you have permission to access the file on a network drive.  Download uses a different protocol for accessing the file than direct opening the file.  An S3 stream is downloading.  Does python download or opens the file remotely?

Comment: There is a ZIP specification the specifies the format of the zip file which zip utilities use.  A zip file is similar to the File System where there are Directories with pointers to the data.  the Directories contain the file size and date.  The directories are fixed size records (one for each file) and end with a null.

Comment: I can't answer how to do this off the top of my head in C#, but the basic idea in Python would [look something like this](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/2fc857f887d87d3133f6cb6767fea3e4), turning the reads from a Zip library into S3 requests.  For a sample ~60gb Zip file I have on S3 it requred reading only around 24kb from S3 in 5 requests to display 250 files.

Comment: Neat! Here's a .NET [Seekable S3 Stream](https://github.com/mlhpdx/seekable-s3-stream) that might just do what Anon Coward's Python example does. Haven't tried it myself to recommend it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this isn't directly possible with built in APIs, as you point out, the Zip header is at the end of the zip file.  Not much of the Zip file actually needs to be read to produce a list of its contents generally.  Though because of a couple of edge cases that can lead to multiple directory entries, and because the size of the directory entries are in fact after the entries themselves, you'll need to be able to seek a bit in the file to produce the list.

AWS S3 does allow you to seek, in a sense, since you can ask for specific ranges of data using byte range requests.  It would be possible to directly map a zip library's calls to `Seek()` and `Read()` to S3 calls. Doing so will likely be very inefficient, as many zip libraries will make many small requests, leading to lots of network traffic.  To work around that, you can request some amount of data beyond what the underlying library requests, and return results from that buffer when possible.

Putting it all together with some sample code looks like this:

```c#
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ZipTestApp
{
    class S3WrapperStream : Stream
    {
        readonly AmazonS3Client _s3;
        readonly string _bucket;
        readonly string _key;
        readonly long _length;
        private long _offset;

        // Keep a local buffer to avoid many small round trips to S3
        // The size here of 32KiB is arbitrary
        readonly byte[] _localBuffer = new byte[32768];
        long _localStart = 0;
        long _localLength = 0;

        // Some stats, purely for debug/demo purposes
        public long TotalBytesRead = 0;
        public long NumberOfReads = 0;

        public S3WrapperStream(AmazonS3Client s3, string bucket, string key)
        {
            _s3 = s3;
            _bucket = bucket;
            _key = key;
            _offset = 0;

            // Get the object size to enable Seek from end operations
            var data = s3.GetObjectMetadata(bucket, key);
            _length = data.ContentLength;
        }

        // Implementations of Stream's properties
        public override bool CanSeek => true;
        public override bool CanRead => true;
        public override long Length => _length;
        public override long Position { get => _offset; set => _offset = value; }

        // Seek simply moves our current pointer around
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
        {
            switch (origin)
            {
                case SeekOrigin.Begin:
                    _offset = offset;
                    break;
                case SeekOrigin.End:
                    _offset = _length + offset;
                    break;
                case SeekOrigin.Current:
                    _offset += offset;
                    break;
            }
            return _offset;
        }

        // Turn reads into S3 calls
        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            if (count > _localBuffer.Length)
            {
                // A big read goes directly to S3
                var req = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = _bucket,
                    Key = _key,
                    ByteRange = new ByteRange(_offset, _offset + count - 1),
                };
                var resp = _s3.GetObject(req);
                var read = resp.ResponseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

                _offset += read;
                NumberOfReads++;
                TotalBytesRead += read;

                return read;
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, the read is small enough to fit in our local buffer
                if (_offset < _localStart || _offset + count >= _localStart + _localLength)
                {
                    // A request for data outside of our buffer came in, fill up to the size
                    // of our buffer first
                    var req = new GetObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = _bucket,
                        Key = _key,
                        ByteRange = new ByteRange(_offset, _offset + _localBuffer.Length - 1),
                    };
                    var resp = _s3.GetObject(req);
                    var read = resp.ResponseStream.Read(_localBuffer, 0, _localBuffer.Length);
                    _localStart = _offset;
                    _localLength = read;

                    NumberOfReads++;
                    TotalBytesRead += _localLength;
                }

                // The data is in our buffer, pull out the correct data and return it
                Buffer.BlockCopy(_localBuffer, (int)(_offset - _localStart), buffer, offset, count);
                _offset += count;
                return count;
            }
        }

        // No need to implement write methods
        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override void Flush() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override void SetLength(long value) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Create a helper to call into S3 based on Stream requests
            var helper = new S3WrapperStream(new AmazonS3Client(), "example-bucket", "example.zip");

            // Pass the helper along to the ZipFile method
            using (var zf = new ZipFile(helper))
            {
                // Just dump out the list of files
                foreach (ZipEntry entry in zf)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", entry.Size, entry.Name);
                }
            }

            // And finally some stats
            Console.WriteLine("Number of reads: {0}", helper.NumberOfReads);
            Console.WriteLine("Bytes read: {0}", helper.TotalBytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

For a test zip file stored in S3, about 60GiB big with around 250 files the zip file, this required 9 calls to S3 pulling down a total of 25,477 bytes.