# Read ZIP from non-seekable stream

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, memorystream

I'm using C# with dotNET 6. I'm using a dockerized S3 storage (ninja) to test everything. The problem I'm facing is when I want to upload to this storage certain files.
I get in input a .zip file as IFormFile. Then I upload this zip file into the storage and it works.
Problems comes when I need to unpack every single item inside and then upload it to this storage.
It works only in this way, making a copy of MemoryStream:

```
private async Task < FileResource > UploadZipFileAsync(Stream source, string containerName, string blobName, string inContentType = null, bool unpack = true) {
    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        await source.CopyToAsync(memoryStream); // Create a copy (memoryStream) of the zip file (source)
        memoryStream.Position = 0; // Set the position to the beginning
    await UploadFileAsync(memoryStream, containerName, $ "{blobName}.zip", inContentType); // Upload the copy of the zip file to the Storage
    FileProperties properties;

    if (unpack) {
        using(var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(source)) {
            foreach(var zipEntry in zipArchive.Entries) {
                using(var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) // Unpack the zip file, and it goes through each file inside it
                {
                    // check if the entry is not a directory
                    if (!zipEntry.FullName.EndsWith("/") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(zipEntry.Name)) {
                        var currentDirectoryName = zipEntry.FullName.Contains("/") ? zipEntry.FullName.TrimEnd(zipEntry.Name.ToCharArray()) : "";
                        new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(zipEntry.Name, out
                            var contentType);
                        var currentDirectory = $ "{blobName}/{currentDirectoryName}";

                        using(var readableFile = new MemoryStream()) {
                            await zipEntryStream.CopyToAsync(readableFile); // Copy the unpacked data (zipEntryStream) into a MemoryStream (readableFile)
                            readableFile.Position = 0; // Set the position to the beginning

                            // Upload the unpacked file to the Storage
                            await storageService.CreateAsync(containerName, $ "{currentDirectory}{zipEntry.Name}", readableFile, contentType ?? "application/octet-stream");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    properties = await storageService.GetFilePropertiesAsync(containerName, $ "{blobName}.zip");
    var fileResource = new FileResource {
        BlobName = blobName,
            BlobContainerName = properties.ContainerName,
            Size = properties.Size,
            MD5 = properties.MD5,
            ContentType = "Folder",
            Uri = properties.Uri
    };

    return fileResource;
}
```

}

The problem is that I don't want to use MemoryStream, due to possible issues when uploading large amounts of datas. If I don't use memory stream, everytime I get the error 'Input stream must be seekable', and the classic Stream is not Seekable (MemoryStream it is).
I'm actually using two times here the MemoryStream to make everything work:
First time because after I upload the source to the storage (zipped) the stream endend and I'm not able to create a new ZipArchive from this same source cause it ended, but I can make it work passing to the method the IFormFile and create two different Stream.
The second one where I need to change the logic.

I tried to save the opened file into a variable, but it is not working because it is a Stream and not seekable.

Comment: You can't force a stream that isn't seekable, eg a network stream, to become seekable. You can't tell the remote server to go back 5 bytes or send the same data again. You'll have to either rethink the logic or cache the stream data, either in memory or a file.

Comment: There's no problem with ZIP files either - you could send the raw data to storage as-is. If you want to unpack them and send the individual files though, you'll have to cache the data

Comment: The reason the stream needs to be seekable is [the structure of a ZIP archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#Structure) which puts the directory at the end of the file. The information is repeated in local file headers but may not be valid. If you really need to unzip a network stream you'll need a different library, eg [SharpCompress](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress/)

Comment: I'm just seeing SharpCompress, having some issues creating the RarArchive.. the fact is that I need all those files unzipped in my storage, but if not seekable, S3 storage won't let me upload them.. With AzureBlob storage is working fine, it's just S3 which doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: Your code doesn't run on the S3 or Azure Blob servers, it runs in a VM or container which has a local file system. Even lambdas/functions run in a container. You can unzip the files to your local storage and send them to S3

Comment: I don't have yet an S3 Cloud storage, I'm actually working with a dockerzied S3 Ninja one before I can actually try it on the cloud.. But if it is not working on the dockerized storage, probably it won't work either with the cloud one..

Comment: You'll never use S3 for *local* storage. Your code will never run on an S3 server. Where do you intend to run your code? Why do you assume you won't be able to store files into a temporary folder?

Comment: S3 supports byte-range requests, so it's possible to process a zip file in chunks, for instance, if you want to only enumerate the contents of a remote Zip file, you can [use a custom implementation of Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75584862/2378643) to turn seeks into byte range requests.  If you're going to process all of the zip file, though, it's almost always better to download the zip file to a local storage first.