# How to extract from response url in Mailchimp Batch Operations in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, gzip, extract, tar, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am requesting data via Mailchimp Marketing API using Batch Operations. I receive a `response_body_url` which once clicked, downloads gzipped files locally.

> A GET request to the response_body_url returns a gzipped tar archive of JSON files.

But I would want to extract the same on Python and load it as a JSON array.
Mailchimp has shared a guide about the same, but they have used a function `process_batch_archive` and have not defined what this function is or how it works.
[image]

Here is the link to the guide: [Link](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/run-async-requests-batch-endpoint/#get-the-results-of-a-batch-operation)
Can anyone help me achieve the expected result? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887979/i-want-to-create-a-script-for-unzip-tar-gz-file-via-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import tarfile
def process_batch_archive():
    if fname.endswith("tar.gz"):
        tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz")
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()
    elif fname.endswith("tar"):
        tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:")
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()
```