# How to download 7z file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.6

I want to download the file, it may be zip/7z. when I used the following code it is giving an **error for the 7z** file.

```
import requests, zipfile, StringIO

zip_file_url = "http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/wxDbViewer.zip"
try:
 r = requests.get(zip_file_url, stream=True)
 z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
 print "Connection refused"
```

Comment: Can you put that _error for the 7z_, please?

Comment: zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: have a watch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083235/unzipping-file-results-in-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure the HTTP status code is 200 when requesting the file, and write out the file in binary mode:

```
import os
import requests

URL = "http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/wxDbViewer.zip"
filename = os.path.basename(URL)

response = requests.get(URL, stream=True)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
        out.write(response.content)
else:
    print('Request failed: %d' % response.status_code)
```

The downloaded file will then appear in the directory where the script is being run if the request was successful, or an indication the file could not be downloaded.