# Odoo 12. How to convert Binary File to Zip?

Tags: python, odoo, binaryfiles, zip, odoo-12

I need to import a zip file that will contain only xml files.

My wizard looks like this:

```
class ZipImportsWizard(models.Model):
    _name = 'import.zip.dte'

    type = fields.Selection([('purchase', 'Purchases'),('sale', 'Sales'),], string="Type", default="purchase")
    file = fields.Binary(string='ZIP File', store=True)
```

I need to open this zip file and check the content.
If the content is OK, I have to send this to another method.

The problem is, when I upload the file, it converts to a Binary file, so I can't user zipfile library to work with it.

How can I convert this Binary file to a Zip file again to work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution by myself, but also thanks to @astronautlevel anwers in this [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083235/unzipping-file-results-in-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file)

```
from odoo import fields, models, _
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import zipfile
import tempfile

class ZipImportsWizard(models.Model):
    _name = 'import.zip.dte'

    type = fields.Selection([('purchase', 'Purchases'),('sale', 'Sales'),], string="Type", default="purchase")
    file = fields.Binary(string='ZIP File', store=True)
    file_name = fields.Char('File name')

    def read_files_from_zip(self):
        file = base64.decodestring(self.zip_file)
        fobj = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        fname = fobj.name
        fobj.write(file)
        fobj.close()

        zipzip = self.zip_file
        f = open(fname, 'r+b')  
        data = f.read()
        f.write(base64.b64decode(zipzip))
        pos = data.find(b'\x50\x4b\x05\x06')
        f.seek(pos + 22)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'r') as zip_file: 
            # do some stuff
            
            f.close()

        return
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with odoo; but:

*If* you have a bytes variable (binary data), you can read it as a Zipfile with the standard python libraries using [io.BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=bytesio#io.BytesIO) and [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html):

```py
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile

 # I assume ths contains the zipfile uploaded by the user.
 uploaded_zipfile = fields.Binary(string='ZIP File', store=True)

with BytesIO(uploaded_zipfile) as fp:
   userzip = zipfile.ZipFile(fp, 'r')

   # You can extract the zip like this:
   userzip.extractall()

   # Or you can check the contents without extracting all the file
   whats_inside_the_zip = userzip.infolist()
```

Comment: I tried your code. Unfortunately it didn't work and the problem is in "userzip = zipfile.ZipFile(fp, 'r')" line.... it returned: "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file"

Comment: What's the class returned by fields.Binary() ? I asumed that was 'bytes'.

Comment: yes exactly. I assume I have to convert that to a zip