# zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file on trying to save docx file in the filesystem

Tags: python, backend, fastapi, docx, python-docx

I am using FastAPI to retrieve the docx file from the frontend as bytes file and to save it on the backend's filesystem. For this purpose I installed the python-docx library. However, when I am trying to run the following code, just like it is said in python-docx docs (https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html#opening-a-file-like-document)

```
async def create_file(textfile: UploadFile, user):
    path = os.path.abspath(textfile.filename)
    f = open(textfile.filename, 'rb')
    document = Document(f)
    f.close()
```

It throws an error:
`zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

I tried to use the following solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11385480/21602190) but as I use bytes, it is pointless.

Comment: Can you open the docx file in Word?  It looks like you might have a corrupt file.  The error may be in that code rather than the opening code.

Comment: Yes, I can. One important thing to note - my backend is dockerized, maybe that can provoke the issue.

Comment: I managed to save it eventually, but it saves weird gibberish into the file instead of actual text, how can I decode it?