# Unzip Tar-Files with python

Tags: python

I would like to unpack tar files and put them in the folder, but I only know zip data. I've tryed this one, but nothin happend.. i only get "Not possible to extract" response.

```
zipfiles = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob('C:/Data/test/Test1/*')]  
    
for zipfile in zipfiles:
                new_dirname = zipfile.replace('.bin.', '_')
                try:
                    os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}')
                except:
                    print(f'output/{new_dirname} already exists')
                try:
                    os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}/full')
                except:
                    print(f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir already exists')
                try:
                    file = tarfile.open('C:/Data/test/Test1/')
                    file.extractall('output/{new_dirname}/full')
                    file.close()
                    
                except:
                    print ("Not possible to extract")
```

Comment: Please focus your question on a single specific problem. How far into the process you described have you gotten / which part is giving you trouble? Can you extract the stem from the zipfile name? Can you do the substitutions to create the target directory name? Can you create the target directory? Can you unpack the zipfile to that directory?

Comment: working with zip files in the python std lib was a little bit wonky at first. here is what you need to get started. https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html. there are also plenty of websites that have very clear examples of how to unzip and name folders accordingly.. you just need to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current working directory contains all the **.zip* files, the following python script will create output directories with *.bsd.* and *.zip* substrings removed from the name. It will subsequently extract the contents of each compressed *zipfile* to the target subdirectory.

Create a directory called *output*. My current directory has *zipfiles* `1234.bsw.5677.zip` with 3 archived text files and `1342.bsw.7756.zip` with 2 archived text files.

```
import glob
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

zipfiles = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(r'./*.zip')]

for zipfile in zipfiles:
    new_dirname = zipfile.replace('.bsw.', '_').replace('.zip', '')
    try:
        os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}')
    except:
        print(f'output/{new_dirname} already exists')
    try:
        os.mkdir(f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir')
    except:
        print(f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir already exists')

    with ZipFile(f'./{zipfile}') as zipObject:
        zipObject.extractall(path=f'output/{new_dirname}/subdir')
```

The structure of *output* is now:

```
output
├── 1234_5677
│   └── subdir
│       ├── fileA.txt
│       ├── fileB.txt
│       └── fileC.txt
└── 1342_7756
    └── subdir
        ├── fileA.txt
        └── fileB.txt
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But it is till not working. I get following response: raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file. but i can open it with 7z. is it possible to open it raw or something?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083235/unzipping-file-results-in-badzipfile-file-is-not-a-zip-file ... some things to try: 1. check your file with the linux "file" command 2. see if you can unzip your files with linux "unzip" command, perhaps it's really a gzipped archive? If you are on windows, maybe you have WSL installed in order to use these commands. I would read through the SO link I posted at the top quite carefully, it looks like there are a few ways others have solved problems with that error message. Best of luck!